# Populate cells based on matching name from other cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Im working on an excel spreadsheet that has three columns.
Column A is a mass number of names with duplicates
Column C has the same names as the first but with no duplicates
Column D has corresponding IDS which tie to the names in Column C

It looks something like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A |  | Name A | 1 |
| Name A |  | Name B | 7 |
| Name A |  | Name C | 56 |
| Name B |  | Name D | 23 |
| Name B |  | Name E | 222 |
| Name B |  |  |  |
| Name B |  |  |  |
| Name C |  |  |  |

How can I populate Column B with Column C's numbers by corresponding name. Like...If Column A Name A = Column C Name A THEN COLUMN B = Column C

It should look like this when completed:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A | 1 | Name A | 1 |
| Name A | 1 | Name B | 7 |
| Name A | 1 | Name C | 56 |
| Name B | 7 | Name D | 23 |
| Name B | 7 | Name E | 222 |
| Name B | 7 |  |  |
| Name B | 7 |  |  |
| Name C | 56 |  |  |

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or SUMIF.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, VLOOKUP is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was solved using =VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)